# How do I configure tox so it produces a wheel?

Tags: python, python-wheel, tox

According to the docs, tox creates "a source distribution of the current project by invoking `python setup.py sdist`".

How do I configure tox so it produces a wheel instead and then uses it for testing?:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***tox 4***

Set [`package = wheel`](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#package) in tox configuration.

---

***tox 3***

There is a *tox* plugin that seems to do exactly that. I haven't tested it so I can't vouch for it personally:

- [`tox-wheel`](https://pypi.org/project/tox-wheel/)

Alternatively you could read these discussions on this exact topic, there are some workarounds mentioned in there:

- https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/185
- https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/232

Comment: tox 4 has added support for wheels and is **not** compatible with `tox-wheel`. In tox 4 you can add `pacakge = wheel` to the `[testenv]` config in `tox.ini`.

Comment: @AbidH.Mujtaba Thanks for the info. I trust you, I updated the answer according to your suggestion without testing myself.